# Why do file upload examples use the name "qqfile"?

Tags: http, file-upload, httpwebrequest

I've noticed that there's seems to be this unwritten convention that when posting a file to a server to call the file in the request "qqfile". Googling away I can't seem to find any explination as to why "qqfile" was chosen.

Is there some reason rooted in history as to why this name is used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because one of the popular AJAX file uploading components uses the namespace `qq` and parameter `qqfile`. Prefixing `file` with the namespace was probably to avoid clashes with other parameters in a form. I don't know why author prefered `qq` as the namespace for his component though, because it resembles neither file upload nor his website, valums.com. He could have wanted something that is short like `$` that doesn't conflict with existing popular libraries.

https://github.com/valums/file-uploader

Comment: See I figured this might be the case, I was hopeful though that there was actually a good reason for it rather than some random convention used in a popular library has been adopted by others.